# How to recover from a Nvidia fail on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have an older Nvidia video card and my PC crashes when installing the driver for the video card in Ubuntu 16.04. When I get to the login screen but no further: after entering my password, the system went into a loop and returned always back to the login screen [with funny stripes present].

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: This is too harsh of a solution. I've had the same problem and the solution is in fact simpler than that.

Comment: Please put your answer in the answer space rather than in the question. It's fine to answer your own question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphics issues after installing Ubuntu 16.04 with NVIDIA graphics](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)

Comment: I'm voting this as too broad because there is no possible answer, the answer is in the question.

Comment: @WindowsinsiderBoomTech That doesn't make it too broad. OP just needs to move the answer to an answer.

Comment: o crap but @chaskes IT GOT MARKED AS HELPFUL :O

Comment: @WindowsinsiderBoomTech Good then. It's an art not a science

Comment: rob, you should accept @Brain's answer. It confirm that it is a solution. It worked for me on 18.04

Answer (score 12):

Edited out of the [question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/760997/revisions) posted by Rob grune:

> To recover, follow these steps:
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> [to exit and get into the TTY mode]
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
> sudo apt-get autoremove
> sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
> echo "nouveau" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
> sudo reboot
> ```
>
> [after reboot, you should be back to operational with the nouveau driver, and can login]
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
> sudo apt-get autoremove
> sudo apt-get autoclean
> ```

Comment: I'm not convinced that `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` is necessary as I didn't nor did I `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf` as the file was not in existence in the installation I was working on. There's also no need to sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa if you aren't using that ppa. All that said I can confirm the rest of the process works. As this system does not require high performance graphics, I'll be sticking with the nouveau driver, however I would imagine that if desired one could try installing the latest nvidia-current package

Comment: Correction: the 'autoremove' command lines should both be using apt-get, not apt.

Comment: This worked for me.  (My assessment agrees with @ElderGeek's.)  Thanks!

Comment: @LelandWoodbury You are correct regarding `apt  autoremove`  (fixex) Keep in mind that once your [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges) is  high enough you'll be able to make these corrections yourself.

Comment: I know this question is about 16.04. Just as an update these steps didn't work for me on Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: How?  Even in tty mode I am stuck in a login loop.

Comment: @ChrisMayer, if the lightdm loaded, you could try Ctrl-Alt-F12 to go to your console (without the graphics at all)

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu has [this guide on their own wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection#Problem:__Need_to_fully_remove_-nvidia_and_reinstall_-nouveau_from_scratch) - but that one was last updated 2013-02-06, so I wouldn't put too much trust/hope/faith/work/time in it.

> Here is a recipe which removes all old video drivers, and reinstalls nouveau:
>
> ```
> sudo nvidia-settings --uninstall
> sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
> sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-nv
> sudo apt-get install nvidia-common
> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue with Dell Vostro 1500 (GeForce 8400M GS) after updating to the recent Ubuntu 16.04.2  and using the `nvidia-340` driver. It took me almost a day to resolve it. Here in shortcut what you can try:

First of all press **CTRL+ALT+F1** to get to the text console. Then log in.

Do `cat /var/log/gpu-manager.log`. If you see something like this:

```
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/4.4.0-72-generic/updates/dkms
Found nvidia module: nvidia_340_uvm.ko
Is nvidia loaded? yes
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? yes
...
```

Then the reason for the login loop is most likely that the nvidia kernel DRI module is blacklisted. This might be because `bumblebee` was previously installed with an older version of the nvidia driver (in my case `nvidia-304`) and now is no longer used. If not **purge deleted** it leaves config files in `/etc`, among them also module blacklists. The blacklisted module causes the X server to fail to initialize after logging in, which results in the login loop.

Check whether bumblebee is installed:

```
apt list --installed | grep bumble
```

If not (no output of the above command) check if `/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf` exists:

```
ls -l /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf
```

If it exists just delete it:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf
```

And now try again either by rebooting or by running:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

You can also see the [detailed problem analysis](https://askubuntu.com/questions/847869/service-lightdm-modifing-etc-alternatives-x86-64-linux-gnu-gl-conf/907857#907857) in my other post.

Comment: thank you! This was the 2nd time when I faced with this issue and I was close to remove the nvidia driver when I found your comment.
It fixed my issue. This should be the accepted answer!