# service lightdm modifing /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf

Tags: nvidia, lightdm, update-alternatives

I've installed nvidia-367 on my system (Ubuntu 16.04). For a reason i don't know, restarting the lightdm service leads to a modification of `/etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf`.

I run manually:

```
root@tron:~# update-alternatives --config x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
There are 3 choices for the alternative x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf (providing /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf).

  Selection    Path                                       Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/nvidia-367/ld.so.conf              8604      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/nvidia-367-prime/ld.so.conf        8603      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/nvidia-367/ld.so.conf              8604      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf   500       manual mode

Press  to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 0
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-367/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
```

and `service lightdm restart` ending up with:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf (providing /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf).

  Selection    Path                                       Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/nvidia-367/ld.so.conf              8604      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/nvidia-367-prime/ld.so.conf        8603      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/nvidia-367/ld.so.conf              8604      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf   500       manual mode

Press  to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

again. That problem is, that with the wrong `ld.so.conf` the nvidia driver can not be loaded:

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[  1649.307] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[  1649.308] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[  1649.308] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[  1649.308] (II) Unloading nvidia
[  1649.308] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
```

Any ideas what, where and why the restart touches these alternative-settings?

```
root@tron:~# dpkg -s nvidia-367 | grep 'Version'
Version: 367.57-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
root@tron:~# dpkg -s lightdm | grep 'Version'
Version: 1.18.3-0ubuntu1
```

P.S. I tried already to purge nvidia* and reinstalling the driver, without any success.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue with Dell Vostro 1500 (GeForce 8400M GS, the `nvidia-340` driver) after updating to the recent Ubuntu 16.04.2. It took me almost a day to find out.

It turned out that after

- setting the alternatives back auto (i.e. nvidia proprietary drivers)
- running ldconfig
- and manually inserting the DRI modules (`sudo modprobe nvidia_340 nvidia_340_uvm nvidiafb`)

`startx` run from commandline started X correctly **with** the proprietary driver. Also the display manager when run manually (not as a systemd service) was using the proprietary driver.

After some more investigation it turned out that the culprit was the `/usr/bin/gpu-manager` (run via `/lib/systemd/system/gpu-manager.service`). Its log `/var/log/gpu-manager.log` was saying:

```
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/4.4.0-72-generic/updates/dkms
Found nvidia module: nvidia_340_uvm.ko
Is nvidia loaded? yes
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? yes
```

And eventually it updated the alternatives to the `mesa/ld.so.conf`.

From this point on it was easy to find out that the `nvidia-340` module was indeed blacklisted in `/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf`

This was apparently a leftover from a previous driver `nvidia-304`, which was using `bumblebee`. The `nvidia-340` driver doesn't use `bumblebee`.

So simply **deleting** `/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf` solved the problem.
The other alternative is to **purge delete** previous nvidia driver installation, as other tutorials say. Obviously I haven't sufficiently purged the previous driver installation...

Comment: :D thanks. same reason for me. shouldn't `apt-get remove --purge nvidia*` remove that bumblebee conf too?