# Make "recovery mode" write to files when file system is read-only?

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am trying to install Nvidia Driver 384.59. in 16.04 LTS.
I bought a Nvidia 1050TI graphics card, which works in Windows 10,  but Ubuntu can't start a UI. -  or rather it tries - I see the GUI login prompt for a second or two, hear a "clunk" on my speakers, and the screen clears to black with a blinking cursor, (no prompt) in the upper left corner.

It will give me the recovery boot menu, and then a text box that I'm in low graphics mode.  after that all choices seem to lead to the "flash of a GUI"- CLUNK- black screen.   I have tried to use "drop to root prompt", but the file system is read only, so I can't use apt to upgrade my drivers.

Comment: Boot with `nomodeset`, then install drivers from Ubuntu repos or from a PPA. Don't install them from a `.run` file.

Comment: you can make RW if you follow the the recommended topic. But it doesn't help in your original problem with the nvidia driver. The solution might be: check whether the `bumblebee` package is installed or its config file is presented. Remove the package and delete the config file. [Details are here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760997/how-to-recover-from-a-nvidia-fail-on-ubuntu-16-04#answer-907869)

Answer (score 4):

You need to remount the file system by the

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

command to get it writable.

Comment: @DavidFoerster It is always mounted as read-only in a recovery console.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that this is in the recovery console. Never mind then.