# Stuck upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, nvidia, upgrade

I tried to upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04 but my system doesn't boot properly. It got stuck in the rebooting phase and all i get when i boot is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWmxK.jpg) and nothing else.

I tried everything stated here [dev/sda1: clean, this message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-wont-c) but nothing.

I also managed to get to the log-in screen (somehow from the recovery mode) but whenever i pressed log-in it flashed some [OK] and some words but i didn't get in.

The only thing that i haven't tried is to purge the nvdia drivers which i don't know how to exactly do.

I've got dual boot and Windows work fine.

Comment: Purging Nvidia drives depends on how they were installed. But in this situation I suggest booting a live session, backup what you need and install from scratch, much faster (and with expected better results) than troubleshooting a failed online upgrade.

Comment: @MichaelBay yeah i'll probably do that , thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to overcome this by purging the nvidia drivers. I followed the instructions from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/820179) post.